# how does one read files in subfolders with minizip

Tags: c++, zip

For a project is have to read some zip files.
everything is okey but when is want to read from a folder in a zip file
it does not work. or i just dont know how zip works in c++.
ive searched all over the internet and could not find an answer.

Comment: I really didn't understand your question well, but my guess is you are trying write a C++ program that'll open files which are inside an archive?

Comment: yes, and in that archive i have some folders with data that i want to extract

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can recall from working with minizip in the past, all the files in the folder hierarchy are returned at the same time. You just need to compare against each file's path name to find out which ones match the folder you want to read.

```
zipFile zip = unzOpen(zipfilename); 
if (zip) {
  if (unzGoToFirstFile(zip) == UNZ_OK) {
    do {
      if (unzOpenCurrentFile(zip) == UNZ_OK) {
        unz_file_info fileInfo;
        memset(&fileInfo, 0, sizeof(unz_file_info));

        if (unzGetCurrentFileInfo(zip, &fileInfo, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == UNZ_OK) {
          char *filename = (char *)malloc(fileInfo.size_filename + 1);
          unzGetCurrentFileInfo(zip, &fileInfo, filename, fileInfo.size_filename + 1, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
          filename[fileInfo.size_filename] = '\0';

          // At this point filename contains the full path of the file.
          // If you only want files from a particular folder then you should compare
          // against this filename and discards the files you don't want. 
          if (matchFolder(filename)) {
            unsigned char buffer[4096];
            int readBytes = unzReadCurrentFile(zip, buffer, 4096);
            // Do the rest of your file reading and saving here.
          }

          free(filename);
        }  

        unzCloseCurrentFile(zip);
      }
    } while (unzGoToNextFile(zip) == UNZ_OK);
  }
  unzClose(zip);
}
```

I don't have the ability to test this code at the moment, so there may be some errors, but hopefully you can see the general idea of how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on James answer here is the tested code.

```
bool mftpd_unzip(char *file, char *dest)
{
    char ch1, ch2;
    int tpos;
    char *tmp;
    int dlen;
    int offset;
    char *dir = (char *)malloc(TRANSPORT_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    zipFile zip = unzOpen(file);
    bool ret = false;
    void *lh = mftpd_log_instance();
    unsigned char buffer[4096];
    FILE *fd = NULL;
    
    if(zip)
    {
        if(unzGoToFirstFile(zip) == UNZ_OK)
        {
            /* Create the dest dir */
            dlen = sprintf(dir, "%s", dest);
            dir[dlen] = 0x0;
            create_nested_directories(dir, dlen);
            
            do
            {
                if(unzOpenCurrentFile(zip) == UNZ_OK)
                {
                    unz_file_info fileInfo;
                    memset(&fileInfo, 0, sizeof(unz_file_info));
                    
                    if(unzGetCurrentFileInfo(zip, &fileInfo, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == UNZ_OK) 
                    {
                        char *filename = (char *)malloc(fileInfo.size_filename + 1);
                        unzGetCurrentFileInfo(zip, &fileInfo, filename, fileInfo.size_filename + 1, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
                        filename[fileInfo.size_filename] = '\0';
                        
                        if(filename[fileInfo.size_filename-1] == '/')
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tmp = strrchr(filename, '/');
                            if(tmp)
                            {
                                tpos = (int)(tmp - filename) + 1;
                                ch1 = filename[tpos];

                                /* Create the dest dir */
                                offset = sprintf(dir+dlen, "%s", filename);
                                *(dir+dlen+offset) = 0x0;
                                
                                ch2 = dir[(dlen + tpos)];
                                dir[(dlen + tpos)] = 0x0;
                                //log_data(LOG_VERBOSE, lh, "Complete dir: %s", dir);
                                create_nested_directories(dir, (dlen+tpos));

                                dir[(dlen + tpos)] = ch2;
                                //log_data(LOG_VERBOSE, lh, "Complete file: %s", dir);
                                fd = fopen(dir, "w+");
                                if(fd == NULL) 
                                {
                                    //log_data(LOG_VERBOSE, lh, "Could not open file %s", dir);
                                    goto end;
                                }
                                
                                dir[dlen] = 0x0;
                                filename[tpos] = ch1;
                               
                                while(true)
                                {
                                    offset = unzReadCurrentFile(zip, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                                    if(offset > 0)
                                    {
                                        buffer[offset] = 0;
                                        fwrite(buffer, 1, offset, fd);
                                        //log_data(LOG_VERBOSE, lh, "Wrote %d bytes of data\n%s", offset, buffer);
                                    }
                                    else if(offset == 0) //end of file
                                    {
                                        fclose(fd);
                                        fd = NULL;
                                        //log_data(LOG_VERBOSE, lh, "Reached end of file");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else //if offset < 0
                                    {
                                        fclose(fd);
                                        fd = NULL;
                                        //log_data(LOG_ERROR, lh, "Got zlib error %d", offset);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //log_data(LOG_ERROR, lh, "File: %s, check here ...", filename);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }while(unzGoToNextFile(zip) == UNZ_OK);
        }
        unzClose(zip);
        ret = true;
    }

end:    
    free(dir);
    return ret;
}
```